# Jquery toggle issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

i just made a jquery work to hide and show a link on a image. the 'a' seated as position absolute on image.

To do this, i made this code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var caseStudySlider = $('div.case-study-slider img');
    caseStudySlider.bind('mouseover',function(e){
        $(e.target).closest("a").toggle();
    })
})
```

and this this my HTML code as well on the page :

```
<div class="case-study-slider">
       <span class="slider-player"><a href="case-study-page-b.html"></a></span>
       <img height="270" width="702" alt="slider" src="images/slide-space-holder-type2.jpg" />
</div>
```

But it's not work. any one help me that, what this the issue with my code?

Thanks on Advance!.

Answer (score 3):

The code

```
$(e.target).closest("a")
```

starts at the mouseover target (most likely `img`?) and looks for a link upwards in the tree.  Your link isn't directly up from the image, so the selector doesn't find it.

Given your current html structure, I would instead find the link like this:

```
$(e.target).closest(".case-study-slider").find("a")
```

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing in the link to show.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is that `mouseover` will trigger on entry, but not on exit, so your `.toggle()` doesn't know whether it's coming or going.  Try `.hover()` instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var caseStudySlider = $('div.case-study-slider img');
    caseStudySlider.bind('hover',
        function(e) {
            $(this).siblings("span").children("a").toggle();
        } 
    );
```

});

NB: functions changed to use `.siblings()` as the `a` isn't a child node of the `img`.

**EDIT** changed to the single callback version of `.hover()` which is more consistent with using `.toggle()` instead of the dual callback version using `.show()` and `.hide()`.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    var caseStudySlider = $('div.case-study-slider img');
    caseStudySlider.bind('hover', function(e){
            $(e.target).sibling("span").css({border : '1px solid red'});
        }, 
        function(e){
            $(e.target).sibling("span").css({border : '1px solid green'});
        }
    );

});

Comment: The function `.sibling()` call will return `undefined` and cause errors. Try `.siblings()` instead.